# Issues adding List as Values into Dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am having issues in the PART II of the below code. The file has duplicate entries for `"Veth"`, `"Po"`, `"Eth"`. Such as:

```
23       0050.5681.6e60    dynamic   10         F    F  Veth1300

23       0050.5681.6e60    dynamic   10         F    F  Veth1400

23       0050.5681.6e60    dynamic   10         F    F  Veth1500
```

My whole idea is to use the MAC (`"0050.5681.6e60"`) as unique key and match and capture the interfaces (`"Veth1300"`) into a list as values with the MAC. Something like:

```
0050.5681.6e60 : [Veth1300, Veth1400, Veth1500]
```

For some reason my code in Part II is not achieving the goal. My Regex portion in Part I is working as desired. I keep getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\Mastin_Veth.py", line 24, in <module>

if dict1[mac] != None:

KeyError: '0050.5681.6e60'
```

Could someone help diagnose the issue. (below code indentation is wrong as could not post code)

```
import re
MAC_keys = set()
dict1    = dict()
#Part I
with open('C:/Python27/dup_MAC_SR629930635.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        regex = re.compile(r"\*\s*[0-9]{1,}\s*([0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*(Veth\d+|Eth.*|Po\d+)$",re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        r = regex.search(line)
        MAC_Key,MAC_associated_VETH = r.groups()
        MAC_keys.add(MAC_Key)

#Part II
for mac in MAC_keys:              # Iteration over SET of Keys
    with open('C:/Python27/dup_MAC_SR629930635.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            regex = re.compile(r"\*\s*[0-9]{1,}\s*([0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}.[0-9a-z]{4}).*(Veth\d+|Eth.*|Po\d+)$",re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
            r = regex.search(line)
            MAC_Key,MAC_associated_VETH = r.groups()
            if mac == MAC_Key:
                #get the value associated with the key
                if dict1[mac] != None:
                    tmp_values_list = list(dict1[mac])
                    tmp_values_list.append(MAC_associated_VETH)
                    dict1.update({mac:tmp_values_list })
                elif dict1[mac] == None:
                    tmp_values_list = [MAC_associated_VETH]
                    dict1[mac] = tmp_values_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the keys in Part I to the set `MAC_Keys`, but they aren't in `dict1`; it's still an empty dictionary, hence `KeyError` on `dict1[mac]`.

You could use `dict1.get(mac)`, which *will* return `None` if the key isn't there. Also, you should really check for `None` as `is not None`, rather than `!= None`, and the `elif` is pointless - it's `None` or it isn't, just put `else`.

However, this seems like an overcomplicated way of doing things. Iterating over the keys in the set and the whole file each time is inefficient, particularly given that you can just check `if MAC_Key in MAC_Keys:`. Also, using `tmp_values_list` and `update` is a long way round, you can just `append` directly to `dict1[mac]`.

Instead, I would suggest:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split()
        out[parts[1]].append(parts[6])
```

This does everything in a single pass, without needing regular expressions. Even if you keep the regular expressions, a single loop and `defaultdict` will make your code clearer and easier to write and maintain.